# Find greatest and least value from mysql field which is having non zero and null values

Tags: mysql

Find greatest and least value from mysql field which result should not be

`zero` or `null`,

we have tried,

```
SELECT LEAST(MIN(`product_price`), MIN(NULLIF(`product_special_price`,'0'))) as min_price,
    GREATEST(MAX(`product_price`), MAX(NULLIF(`product_special_price`,'0'))) as max_price
        FROM (`tbl`)
```

in this we are getting NULL result when `product_special_price` is not entered

[Example SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48c3e/1)

current output / problem :

[image]

Comment: The question and the query you presented don't seem to fit. Please share the exact requirements, the table's structure, some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that sample.

Comment: @Mureinik, added fiddle please have a look

Comment: Why not use a `WHERE` clause to filter out `NULL` values?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a `WHERE` statement to filter out `0` and `NULL` values:

```
SELECT MIN(column) AS least, MAX(column) AS greatest
FROM table
WHERE column != 0 AND column IS NOT NULL
```

Where you substitute `column` and `table` with the corresponding column and table respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the result you were expecting, so I'm not completely sure if I read your question right, but a CASE statement could be used to eliminate the values you don't want. So when the value of the column is 0, you just don't include it in the LEAST/GREATEST functions. Rewriting you SQL this way as per below, I get min_price 72 & max_price 81 (using your SQL fiddle data) - is this what you were after?

```
SELECT 
CASE tbl.simple_price
WHEN 0 THEN MIN(`price`)
ELSE LEAST(MIN(`price`), MIN(`simple_price`)) 
END as min_price,
CASE tbl.simple_price
WHEN 0 THEN MAX(`price`)
ELSE GREATEST(MAX(`price`), MAX(`simple_price`)) 
END as max_price
FROM (`tbl`)
```